# Old Packard laptop, flickering output via VGA to HDMI converter 16.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I tried installing Ubuntu 16.04 on my MIL's old Packard Easynote and it seems to work mostly. What she and her BF want to do is play some music via Spotify and show some images from a USB on their TV.

My issue is when connecting via VGA->converter->HMDI to a Sharp TV the laptop and TV screen flicker. In the screen setup i tried detecting screens and the screen was not detected properly. I tried both 1024*768 and 800*600 on the TV output alone and on both screens. Finally i got a jumbled up screen on both the laptop and the TV but the image was stable. Is at an issue of resolution of update ratio? How should i solve it? Would it be worth seting up resolutions manually?

Comment: Not all VGA-Converters are created equally.  Have you used that converter in a different setup, perhaps windows, and know it works properly?

Comment: Yes, It works with the same computer with windows XP.

Comment: Do you remember the resolution that was used by Windows, and did you duplicate it in Ubuntu?

Comment: No unfortunately i dont. The TV itself however shows 1024*764 in the corner on occasion on the HDMI channel. Is there a gui resolution changer for the hdmi out i can try maybe?